# iframes: accessing parent from a child element inside a iframe

Tags: javascript

I have an Iframe inside of a page that has the src set to a file on the same local machine (not cross domain).

So I have a page that looks like this:

```
<html>
 <head/>
 <body><iframe id="something" src="somepage.html"/></body>
</html>
```

Inside of the iframe there is some contents

```
    <html>
    <head/>
     <body>
      <li>
        <ul>stuff</ul>
      </li>
     </body>
    </html>
```

My question is, I have a variable (in my index page) that is currently pointing to the element `var element = <ul>stuff</ul>` which is inside of the iframe.

From this variable I want to be able to access the parent iframe and get the id 'something'.

I have been attempting some jquery using find with no luck

```
$(element).find('iframe')
```

And I am wondering where I am going wrong... I have googled other solutions but they are all related to being outside of the iframe looking in, I guess I am inside looking out! is there anyone else out there that could help shed some light?

Comment: Your question is confusing to me, can clear it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be very difficult to find the id of the iframe element without something like its name.

But supposing you know the name of the html file in the iframe ("somepage.html"), which seems natural, you can do this to get the element containing the iframe in the parent document :

```
var $matching = $(parent.document).find('iframe').filter(function(){
    var srcTokens = this.src.split('/');
    return srcTokens[srcTokens.length-1]=='somepage.html';
});
```

Here's the "somepage.html" file I used to test, logging the id in the console :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </head>
     <body>
      <li>
        <ul>stuff</ul>
      </li>
      <script>
          var $matching = $(parent.document).find('iframe').filter(function(){
              var srcTokens = this.src.split('/');
              return srcTokens[srcTokens.length-1]=='somepage.html';
          });
          console.log($matching.attr('id'));
          </script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT : as was seen by Serjio, it's possible to use `location.href` if you don't know the name of the html file.

Answer (score 1):

At first, it's a good practice to set name for iframe if you want to access some data in it. After that to access iframe's DOM you can use:

```
$('ul', window.frames['iframe_name'].document);
```

To access global variables

```
alert(window.frames['iframe_name'].some_global_var_or_function_of_iframe)
```

If you want to get some parent data inside iframe:

```
$('selector', parent.document) // for DOM
alert(parent.some_global_var_or_function_of_parent_window)
```

**EDIT**
So in your case just use:

```
$('iframe', parent.document).filter(function(iframe){
    // you can compare iframes like this
    return iframe.getAttribute('src') == location.href
}).attr('id')
```

Comment: In this "solution", you find the id only if you already know it (or know the name). I don't think this is what is required.

Comment: Hi Serjio, thank you for your input however I think this is the wrong answer, I must know the name of my iframe, when from the element inside of the iframe I want to ask what my containing iframes name is, does this make a bit more sense?

Comment: @John check **EDIT** section. This code `$(element).find('iframe')` is completely wrong because there are not iframes inside your `ul` element as i understood from your question

Comment: @dystroy i was described variable/DOM relations between window and frames (so i able to write that you took some part of my solution but it's ridiculously; hey man we are not children). And i have improved your solution. Also in your answer there is some strange variable `$iframes` that are used nowhere.

Comment: @Serjio The `location.href` use is a worthy addition. But when you copy (even with addition) some answer after having produced obviously wrong ones, it's better to mention it.

Comment: @Serjio No worry. This isn't so important. We're both just trying to find solutions to code problem and to help other coders, there is no offense :)